# It takes several clicks of the shifter to go from smallest cog to next biggest cog, and I get hit the four biggest cogs

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear, shifting, sprocket

When I try to shift from the smallest cog to the next biggest one, I have to shift three times before it moves. Click one and I see the cable tightening. Click two and nothing, and click three and then it moves. But as a result of this, I can't hit my four biggest cogs in the back.

I can manually move the derailer such that it goes to the biggest cog, so it doesn't seem like I need more cable to enable this movement. As soon as I let go of the derailer and peddle, it goes back to 4 short of the biggest cog.

What could be wrong or what could I try to trouble shoot this?

Comment: Check if the derailleur hanger is bent. If it is, get it straightened. Then, read up on how to adjust a derailleur http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment. You might also have inadequate tension in the shift cable, esp. if you can see the cable tighten up significantly -- it should be taut (or nearly so; but with varying tension) depending on what gear you're in.

Comment: Could be as simple as the cable is too loose.

Comment: @mattnz Thanks guys. I didn't see Mattnz comment before I started messing around, but you guys were exactly right. The cable was too loose.

Comment: @Batman you got me on the right track. It was the cable being too loose. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cable was too loose. I had read else where that others were surprised at how loose the cable needed to be. I guess I took that too far and that's what caused the issue.